High Energy Conformer - Why is it the most stable?
I'm doing docking studies. Upon preparing my ligands, I've conducted conformational analysis to them using RDKit and plot their respective potential energies. I'm just confuse why my thesis advisers told me to pick the high energy conformer to dock to my protein. It has nothing to do with my molecular systems, etc. They said that high potential energy conformer is the most stable conformer.
This is the energy diagram and the structure of the conformer with the highest potential energy.


I've read and read a lot of related literatures and clearly they are stating that the low potential energy conformer is more stable. Why does my adviser tell me that "High energy conformer is the most stable"

I can think of reasons you might want to look into high energy conformations, but that does not answer your question, "Is there any theories or concepts i don't know?" which is impossible to answer, and the more particular question of what your advisors might be thinking, not knowing who they are or a fly in the room in which discussions were held. Maybe you misunderstood? What keeps you from asking them this question?

Caryophyllene seems to have been studied extensively. I recommend looking at existing publications of docking studies or simulations. Without some edits this seems otherwise more of a question for academia SE and not for this website. Please see the help pages on what makes a question appropriate for this site.

@BuckThorn I keep asking them this question, but they just stating that that is the standard procedure. I know and read some reasons for high energy conformations, but that just doesn't justify what my adviser told me that "high energy conformer is more stable"

Well a possible explanation is that the lowest E conformation when docked is not the one you obtain for the free molecule. Still, I recommend you rewrite your question. .

In addition to Buck Thorn's comment (lowest energy conformer of an isolated ligand needn't be the one found docking to the host), docking usually leads to a minimum of the sum of the energies of ligand and host.

@Buttonwood yes, but the conformational analysis was done BEFORE docking. My adviser told me to choose the most stable ligand (in a free molecule state) which is the ligand with the highest potential energy. That is why I'm confused.

@CarbonNanotubes If you sketch an isolated molecule e.g., in ChemDraw, Marvin, or tinker together with e.g., Avogadro2 an initial optimization (e.g., UFF, MMFF96s) relaxes the structure to something chemically more reasonable than the (perhaps only 2D) structure you started, either a single, or multiple conformers (e.g. obabel). But like toes on a foot, as soon as you were a shoe (or a molecule binds to an other), some of the initial flexibility is lost in favor of overall E.

My intuition on this is that a high-energy conformation would "give it room" for conformational changes after it forms the ligand where this might not be possible if you're already at a minimum. Or perhaps if it's at a minimum, it would be less likely to form the ligand in the first place because there is no "flexibility" left for necessary adjustments for the bond to take place.
